# C++ parser for OGC Filter Encoding 1.0

Tags: software-recommendations, filter, c++, ogc

I'm developing a C++ application and I have to parse a OGC Filter in order to implement querying functionality on a metadata repository.

Does anyone know any C++ library to parse OGC Filters?